# Nginx - remove trailing slash if it's not a directory

Tags: nginx

I have no problems with redirect, but when I uncomment 2 lines that do "if folder doesn't exist" check, I get 404 error on any page. And I don't understand why, it's basic functionality.

I need to redirect all requests with trailing slash to urls without it. The only exception is when a folder with that url exists.

```
location / {
  #if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
  #}

  index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

You could try an alternative approach and only rewrite *after* try_files has processed the URIs that it can:

```
location {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^ /index.php?q=$request_uri last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.